# Popup not working on MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I have to display a Popup on click of a MenuItem. I have written the below code for that:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <Border>
        <MenuItem Name="ack" Header="ACK" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding AcknowledgeCommand}"  Visibility="{Binding IsAcked, Converter={StaticResource showOnFalse}}" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
    </Border>
    <Separator/>
    <Border>
        <MenuItem Header="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
    </Border>
    <Separator/>
    <Border>
        <MenuItem Header="Goto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Popup Name="infoPopup" Placement="Mouse" HorizontalOffset="-100" VerticalOffset="-100" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="True">
        <Alarms:UserControl_MYUC DataContext="{Binding TopMost}" Background="{DynamicResource DetailPanelCompartmentTitleBg}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SecWindowBtnBorder}"/>
    </Popup>
</ContextMenu>
```

OnClick of the MenuItem, I have written the following code:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    infoPopup.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    infoPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

I am able to see the popup on click of the Info button, but the Popup goes within a second. I want it to be visible till the user clicks some other area or the popup loses focus.
Please suggest what to do.

Comment: How do you show the pop up?

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the answer to your question @NahuelIanni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply  `StaysOpenOnClick="True"` to your MenuItem.

Comment: But the next time I right click on the screen the Popup opens in the same place. I have given the placement = "Mouse" but still the popup opens on the position at which it had earlier opened. How can I get rid of that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `StaysOpen` Boolean to define what you wanted.

```
myPopup.StaysOpen = true;
```

For further information, please refer to the following link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen(v=vs.110).aspx